# SWD optoisolation problem

Tags: opto-isolator, jtag, optoelectronics, swd

I have designed the following optoisolator for SWD interfacing with an STM32 device and J-LINK programmer:

This is the generic schematic:
[image]

And this is a single optoisolator schematic:
[image]

I am not able to interface with the board in the J-Link commander. I see that J-Links attempts to reset the device but fails to communicate. Is there any basic flaw in my design? 
Can the bidirectional SWDIO line be the case? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Out is inverted from In . Is that OK?

Comment: Yes. When LED is ON, the out is LOW. When LED is off, out is high.

Comment: Please explain the resistor values. (All of them appear to be too low.)

Comment: R3 is the closesest one for 10 mA LED current. R5 is from datasheet test circuit design. R1 and R2 are the same as R3, just to have them at hand. I did not want to force any high instantaneous current on the bidirectional patch. Do you have any idea what could be the case?

Comment: What do you see on the STM32 side on SWDIO? You should see the switching sequence, and a target ID read, followed by an ACK (1+3+1 bits), 32 bits data and parity. This much progress occurs mastered by the J-link, and the ID read needs to be seen to show the target is present.

Comment: Or you could buy the ST-LINK/V2-ISOL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right X5 and X6 are making a positive feedback loop. You need a bidirectional optoisolator for SWDIO line. For speeds up to 1 Mhz you can find guidance in this NXP [Application note](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10364.pdf). You also need to see if the 160 ns delay induced by the optocouplers (2x80ns,forward path + backward path) is acceptable for the programmer. You might want to change the point of view and insulate the USB side of the programmer with a device like [USB ISO](https://www.olimex.com/Products/USB-Modules/USB-ISO/) form Olimex

Comment: Thanks for answer. I ended up using Si8605 eventually. Simplified the whole design.

Comment: Good to know. I didn't know if it's a one time solution for a particular issue or a product that you want to sell having cost constraints. For a one time design USB ISO interface is much expensive but gets the maximum speed from the programmer. The opto or Si8605 add some delays in the signals.